# How to control a ready animation?

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I have downloaded from asset store a 3d model that comes with some animations.
At the instructions they gave was to create an animator controller and the animation could be used. I'm beginner using unity and just create and put de animations in animator controller don't make useful, I can't control time, distance of an avatar walks... somebody can help me?

Comment: unity have a pretty good tutorial, https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/animation/animator-controller does it help?  it's a big thing to learn about, takes time

Comment: add animation component assign clip and check on playautomaticallu

Comment: you have to narrow down your question to get an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things you need to learn before you can animate your character.

1. Using the animator controller
2. Using the animation view
3. Basic animation scripting

Unity had conveniently created a comprehensive tutorial on this subject, so beginners such as yourself could learn how to use the program. The link is below:

[Animations Tutorial](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/animation)